# Joomla : Backend not showing editing tabs

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I'm not sure why, but suddenly my joomla is having errors.
Mostly on content and menus.

I can't really describe by the code what is happening, because I also don't understand why.

I'll use my article section to explain and as a comparison.

This is a common 'Edit Article' section in any common joomla.

[image: Joomla Content]
<sub>(source: [joomla.org](https://docs.joomla.org/images/thumb/4/4c/Help-3x-content-article-manager-add-new-article.png/670px-Help-3x-content-article-manager-add-new-article.png))</sub>

And this is what I have in My Joomla

[image: My Joomla]

There is a lot difference between the two, I will summarize :

- There is no 'Alias' field to set the url_aliasing
- There is no 'Content, Publising, Images and Links, etc...' to set publishing options, etc.
- The 'Category' Field is in the top, and the 'tags' field is not changeable

My question is : **What is causing this? Is it extension, article module, or what?**

Please elaborate and provide solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I recommend is to always have updated the site to the latest version.
Both for reasons of safety and features.

Currently Joomla version is 3.4.4

You're working with a version 3.1.4 and compare the screen with a 3.2.1

Comment: Yes, before I am seeing the publishing options, etc... tabs and now all of the sudden I wasn't seeing anything.

Though, I will try to update the joomla. But it will be tricky since my directory permission is only set allowed to /tmp from previous developers.